# How to aggregate two collections in Mongoose/MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

On my study server. I've got two collections with **users** and their **races**. Races has `userId` property in order to know what user made this race. I need to make consolidated object of all users and all races.

**I've got collection of users:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d938ec8b17e522018e327db",
        "name": "max",
        "surname": "buinevich",
        "username": "axe",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**and collection of races:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d93ac4c7076dc212ce187d6",
        "userId": "5d938ec8b17e522018e327db",
        "stageId": "5d939e16d4e51d2eac81827d",
        "title": "test race",
        "time": 33,
        "description": "test desc",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

**So i need to join all users with proper races to have a result like:**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5d938ec8b17e522018e327db",
        "name": "max",
        "surname": "buinevich",
        "username": "axe",
        "races": [{
                    "_id": "5d93ac4c7076dc212ce187d6",
                    "userId": "5d938ec8b17e522018e327db",
                    "stageId": "5d939e16d4e51d2eac81827d",
                    "title": "test race",
                    "time": 33,
                    "description": "test desc",
                    "__v": 0
                }]
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

I dont want to use refs in collection schemas. Maybe something like mongoose aggregate or else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If not using `refs` in **`mongoose schemas`** (although recommended) because **`populate`** comes in very handy to generate hierarchical documents.

Option is to using native **agregation pipeline** [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) that essentially performs **(analogous to LEFT JOIN in SQL)** on the joined collection to populate documents in an array field.

**Aggregation Query:**

```
db.usersCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "racesCollection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "userId",
      as: "races"
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

**Mongoose model aggregation query would look like:**

```
UserModel.aggregate.lookup({
  from: "Races", //or Races.collection.name
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "userId",
  as: "races"
});
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d938ec8b17e522018e327db"),
    "name" : "max",
    "surname" : "buinevich",
    "username" : "axe",
    "__v" : 0,
    "races" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d93ac4c7076dc212ce187d6"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("5d938ec8b17e522018e327db"),
            "stageId" : ObjectId("5d939e16d4e51d2eac81827d"),
            "title" : "test race",
            "time" : 33,
            "description" : "test desc",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```